# Gifted Chat Invalid Date Issue

Tags: react-native, react-native-gifted-chat

I am using react native gifted chat along with firestore, It shows invalid date on message time stamp.
Any guidance how to correct it?
I am using timestamp of gifted chat in the code as follows

```
msg.forEach(item=>
            {
        const data1={
            text:item.text,
            _id:i,
            createdAt:item.createdAt,
            user:item.user,
        }
```

Comment: Getting the same issue, how did you fix it?

Comment: Actually Unable to fix it, I think we need to implement custom code while using it with Firestore

Comment: I'm having the same issue - did you end up needing to write custom code?

Comment: Yes, I removed gifted chat and used my own code in its place

Answer (score 2):

**Date is coming as firebasetime stamp convert it to date. like this.**

```
.onSnapshot((qry) => {
                const messages = qry.docs.map(doc => {
                    const obj = doc.data();
                    // console.log(firebaseData)
                    return {
                        _id: doc.id,
                        ...obj,
                        createdAt: obj.createdAt.toDate(),
                    };
                });

                setMessages(messages);
            });
```

Answer (score 1):

Here, the date will be coming as timestamp we have to manually convert to date by toDate func

```
return { _id: doc.id, ...obj, createdAt: obj.createdAt.toDate(), };
```

This doesn't happen while the system uses the firebase cache so this is the sign that data is coming from firestore and the configuration is alright!